# Proving a certain inequality

Tags: general-topology, inequality

I'm trying to prove the following inequality by purely algebraic means

$$\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}\leq \frac{|x-z|}{1+|x-z|}+\frac{|z-y|}{1+|z-y|}.$$

My arguement is as follows:

Notice that, $|x-z|+|z-y| \geq |x-y|$ and from this inequality we can write $1+|x-z|+|z-y| \geq 1+|x-z| $ and $1+|x-z|+|z-y| \geq 1+|z-y|$. Now,

$$\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|} \leq \frac{|x-z|+|z-y|}{1+|x-z|+|z-y|}\leq \frac{|x-z|}{1+|x-z|}+\frac{|z-y|}{1+|z-y|}.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Why is this tagged as [tag:general-topology]?

Comment: @AymanHourieh Perhaps because metrics and the triangle inequality often appear within topology?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$ and see if it is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: I actually want to prove this by purely algebraic means. Avoid any form of analysis.

Comment: And, in fact, monotonicity is not enough. $f(x)=x^2$ is also increasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$, but it does not fulfill a similar inequality. The point is that $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$ is increasing *and concave* on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: You are right but this is a standard way to show the triangle inequality for metrics of the form $\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$ where d is another metric.

Answer (score 1):

We have

\begin{align}
\frac{|x - y|}{1 + |x - y|} &= 1 - \frac{1}{1 + |x - y|}\\
& \le 1 - \frac{1}{1 + |x - z| + |z - y|}\\
& = \frac{|x - z| + |z - y|}{1 + |x - z| + |z - y|}\\
& = \frac{|x - z|}{1 + |x - z| + |z - y|} + \frac{|z - y|}{1 + |x - z| + |z - y|}\\
& \le \frac{|x - z|}{1 + |x - z|} + \frac{|z - y|}{1 + |z - y|}.
\end{align}

Comment: Why is the 2nd line true?

Comment: @user119264 since $1 + |x - y| \le 1 + |x - z| + |z - y|$, $$\frac{1}{1 + |x - y|} \ge \frac{1}{1 + |x - z| + |z - y|}.$$ Thus $$-\frac{1}{1 + |x - y|} \le - \frac{1}{1 + |x - z| + |z - y|},$$ which implies $$1 - \frac{1}{1 + |x - y|} \le 1 - \frac{1}{1 + |x - z| + |z - y|}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Not that if $x \le y$, then $\frac{x}{1+x}\leq\frac{y}{1+y}$.